# No events being shown when retrieving events using google calendar

Tags: php, events, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am encountering a problem with my code when I am trying to retrieve events on the google calendar. Below is my code:

```
    <?php

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");

// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=calendar to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('client id');
$client->setClientSecret('client secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('redirect uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('developer key');

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

$events = $cal->events->listEvents('email address for google calendar');

echo $events;    
?>
```

When I print out the events of my google calendar, all I get is an empty array. However I am sure that I have several events in my google calendar.

In fact, I event tried to add an event by using the code below:

```
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2013-08-23T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2013-08-23T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);

echo $events;

$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('email address for google calendar', $event);
```

However, when I do this code I end up receiving an error that says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'email address for google calendar'/events?key='key'......................................lib/google-api-php-client/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

As it's an array you need to use print_r instead of echo. Try replacing:

```
echo $events;
```

with

```
print"<pre>".print_r($events, true)."</pre>";
```